# Is identity included in the "key" in predicate logic?

Tags: logic, notation, predicate-logic

So, my exam is in a few days. We've been told to practice setting up a key in predicate logic. .
From what I've understood, a typical key looks something like this:

> $ Lxy$: $x$ likes $y$
>
> $Rx$: $x$ is rich
>
> $j$: John

But, something my lecturer said about identity made me wonder whether or not I should include it in the key (if I am going to use identity, that is). He said that, for example, $x=y$ is the predicate $=xy$ ($x$ is identical to $y$, or something similar), only that since having the "$=$" in the middle is what we're used to (before logic), that's what we do in logic as well.

Thus, I have the impression that it is the same as a predicate (like "$Lxy$"), and therefore wonder whether I should have it in the key or not?
If not, why not? :)

Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear to me what a "key" is ... In general, we can develop first-order logic without equality (i.e."$=$") or adding it to the language. But if you add it to f-o logic, you will treat it syntactically as a predicate (i.e.$x=y$ is treated as an abbreviation for the "official" $=xy$, and this is a well-formed formula of the language). But semantically you cannot treat eqaulity as the other predicates, suitable of different interpretation. If it is present in the language, its meaning must be *fixed* : it is the relation *I =<x,x>* of identity in the domain.

Comment: *key*, Mauro, is being used to define the domain, the predicates that are being used:  e.g. "Let P(x) denote 'x is a police officer', let Q(x) denote 'x is a queen' ..." etc.

Comment: Not usually, no; it's often clear from the context. If "identity" is *loosened* to include, say, equivalence of some form or another, then it's sometimes taken as $Ixy$, for example, but this is a minor issue. You're unlikely to run up against such things just yet.

Answer (score 3):

No need to include it in your key: it seems clear that your instructor accepts $x = y$ as denoting $=_{xy}\quad$

> ...having the "=" in the middle is what we're used to (before logic), that's what we do in logic as well.

So you are free to simply use "$x = y$"
to denote $x = y$.

Comment: Needs another TU ... +1